# Blur shadow around edittext with rounded corners

Tags: android, gradient, shadow, blur

can anyone explain and give me an example - how to add blurred shadow around edittext with rounded corners
like on a picture
[image]

Comment: Isn't it an `EditText` inside a `CardView`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's an elevation. What you need to do is you need to add background with rounded corners to EditText and set margin to the EditText because without margin your shadow will be cutted off.

edittext_background.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/white"/>

    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="8dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="8dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="8dp" android:topRightRadius="8dp"/>
</shape>
```

EditText:

```xml
<EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:elevation="8dp"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext_background"
                android:layout_margin="16dp" />
```

Comment: yes. you are right. too easy to be true )))   I looked for blur shadow...